# How to perform such sum aggregations in bigquery[duplicate records]

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to perform such aggregation in bigquery, avoiding the addition of duplicate records:

An example table with records:

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljrK3.png)

As a result, I would like to get the sum of unique records for id which has [operation_time(unique)] as the latest.

[EXPECTED SUM AGGREGATION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnuCG.png)

Answer (score 0):

haven't tested it but this should work.

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  COUNT(id) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY value ORDER BY opertion_time DESC) AS rnk
  FROM
    your_table)
GROUP BY id
WHERE
  rnk = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Gaurang, works fine only need to edit a bit:  SELECT
  id,
  SUM(value) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY time_start,time_stop,value,id ORDER BY operation_time DESC) AS rnk
  FROM
    test_data)
WHERE
  rnk = 1
GROUP BY id

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to create something like this, maybe someone will find it useful:

```
with test_data as (
  select '2022-01-01 06:00:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:15:00' time_stop,1 value,'id_1' id,'2022-01-01 06:15:14.529364' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:00:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:15:00' time_stop,1 value,'id_1' id,'2022-01-01 06:15:35.510090' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:00:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:15:00' time_stop,1 value,'id_1' id,'2022-01-01 06:15:57.410286' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:00:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:15:00' time_stop,2 value,'id_2' id,'2022-01-01 06:15:14.529364' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:00:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:15:00' time_stop,2 value,'id_2' id,'2022-01-01 06:15:35.510090' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:00:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:15:00' time_stop,2 value,'id_2' id,'2022-01-01 06:15:57.410286' operation_time
  union all 
  select '2022-01-01 06:30:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:45:00' time_stop,1 value,'id_1' id,'2022-01-01 06:45:14.529364' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:30:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:45:00' time_stop,1 value,'id_1' id,'2022-01-01 06:45:35.510090' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:30:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:45:00' time_stop,1 value,'id_1' id,'2022-01-01 06:45:57.410286' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:30:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:45:00' time_stop,2 value,'id_2' id,'2022-01-01 06:45:16.529364' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:30:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:45:00' time_stop,2 value,'id_2' id,'2022-01-01 06:45:33.510090' operation_time
  union all
  select '2022-01-01 06:30:00' time_start,'2022-01-01 06:45:00' time_stop,2 value,'id_2' id,'2022-01-01 06:45:53.410286' operation_time

) 


select sum(value) as sum_value,id FROM(
  select * except(row_num) from (
      select *,
        row_number() over (
        partition by
        time_start,time_stop,value,id
        order by
        operation_time desc
        ) row_num
      from
      test_data) t
  where row_num=1)
 GROUP BY id
```